# Trying to fetch Read food items eaten data from google fit but returning 403 in reponse

Tags: google-fit

**This is the request below:** **For scope : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read**

Also do let me know how to pass multiple scope inorder to fetch auth code via api

POST /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources?dataTypeName=com.google.nutrition&fields=dataSource(dataStreamId) HTTP/1.1
Host: [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com)
Content-length: 0
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer Auth_code
Accept: application/json

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to list nutrition data sources, send a GET request instead of a POST.

Comment: I am not able to find value for what dataSource(dataStreamId) is needed to be insert to fetch the list

Comment: Why do you think you need to pass a value for that at all? According to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters), `fields` is a field mask. How about starting with no field mask, and then working out what you need later.